# How do I deal with falmer and dwemer mechs?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm about to go venturing deep into a dwemer ruin, and I was wondering if someone has some advice for dealing with falmer & dwemer mechs.

Comment: Basically just like you deal with anything. I usually shoot all of the falmer from a distance, they're not really strong. The mechs could be quite a challenge though, try to use ranged attacks if you have them. You can even try to use glitchy spots where they can't hit you, but from where you are able to attack.

Comment: Currently two answers, both downvoted for no apparent reason. Huh?

Comment: One thing not mentioned:  Falmer can't see, so don't worry about light sources... use as much light as you want.  They can hear though, so muffle is critical.  They are not resistant to poison, so use it if you have it, but, they use it all the time, so resistance to poison is useful.

Answer (score 5):

I find falmer are very susceptible to arrows - pick off the leaders first of course.

With mechs - it depends which ones :

- spiders - not much danger in a melee battle.
- spheres - Arrows to damage, but they can close quickly so swap to sword/shield - they are also susceptible to bash damage
- ballistas - make use of cover and snipe with ranged weapons. Up close hit from behind if you can.

Mechs of course are more susceptible to shock damage. Falmers take all damage that hit them. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the regular methods aren't working, Dwemer ruins are filled with traps, and they work against all creatures.  The spinning blade from floor thing tends to be extremely effective and even falmer will run headlong into it, while you can also use fire traps to keep them back and shoot them with arrows/magic.

Comment: I would have thought that there aren't enough traps in most places to deal with all the enemies.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 Dwemer traps are generally resetting, and the spinning blade one I mentioned is usually set off by a pressure plate just before it on either side, so if you are careful you can kite enemies back to it and trigger it while they are chasing you.

Comment: that is true if you want to run through a ruin with a sphere chasing you and shooting at you, while trying to find the trap that you think you passed. Seems better to me to learn some good combat skills. Although daunting when you first meet them, neither falmers, or mechs are invincible and can be defeated even for a low level player.

Comment: @TonySuffolk66 The OP made it sound like he was having trouble beating them on his own, and at this point there's no reason to repeat your answer.  I find tricking enemies into dying to traps extremely satisfying anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I would use bound arrows and bows against all dwemer. weapons with a shock enchantment are best.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to pick off the falmer and the mechs with bows and arrows except for the "Centurion" mech. The Centurion is a large mech with a dwarven warhammer on one hand and a dwarven battle axe on another. It also has a special ability to shoot steam at the player dealing moderate damage. The best way to defeat it I've found is to try to lure it to a small tunnel where it can't fit and attack it from there.